# How to manually specify/mock statistics of tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, statistics, evaluation, optimization

I want to find a way to manually populate the the statistics of tables in PostgreSQL.

Say that table A really has no data, it is empty. I want to make PostgreSQL's cost based optimizer think that there are 1000 rows (and other metrics such as distinct count or histogram of columns) in that table so I can use the mock statistics to evaluate a query.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: This is a clarified follow-up to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013352/how-to-manually-update-the-statistics-data-of-tables-in-postgresql

Comment: I suspect you're going to have problems setting the histogram values. Even though [`pg_statistic`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-statistic.html) is accessible via SQL, it has fields typed `anyarray`, and I'm not sure you can actually set them from SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've took a look at the pg_statistic table and  [pg_stats](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-stats.html) view, in the view I saw that most_common_elems/most_common_elem_freqs/elem_count_histogram were empty, and I'm also a little confused about the correlation. Is there any detailed document about how these metrics are calculated in PostgreSQL? @CraigRinger

Comment: AFAIK, the main documentation is the usually-decently-commented source code, plus the postgresql internals docs for the table structure etc. I haven't messed a great deal with the guts of the stats code. If you have specific "wtf is this" questions about bits of the stats structure you can ask on pgsql-general.

Comment: I see, thanks, I've downloaded the source code of PG. @CraigRinger

Comment: Hi @CraigRinger, do you know where the statistic of total row numbers of tables is stored in PostgreSQL? It seems that pg_statistic only stores information about columns.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks, I see it. If I set autovacuum_enabled = false, toast.autovacuum_enabled = false, then the table will not be analyzed automatically unless I execute the ANALYZE statement, right?

Comment: Think so, but don't do that. Use table-specific autovacuum control parameters. They're discussed in the routine vacuuming section of the manual. Never turn autovacuum off globally - remember, it's required for system tables too!

Comment: Hi @CraigRinger , I've read the analyze.c, finding that only histogram bounds are stored in pg_statistic, does it mean that pgsql uses equal-depth histogram? .. And many databases also store MAX/MIN/AVG value of a column, why doesn't pgsql use them as well?

Comment: I've close-voted this. It requires open-ended discussion beyond the scope of Stack Overflow and can never really have a useful answer.

Comment: I really can't provide ongoing detailed Q&A into the innards of the statistics collector. Perhaps you should consider asking on pgsql-perform or pgsql-general, outlining what you've already done / worked out and your goal. Suggest that you'd really like to be able to simulate table stats - and why.

Comment: @CraigRinger Yeah I see, sorry for troubling you. I've sent my questions to the mailing list already, thanks for your help :)